# How to do margin: 0 auto 0 auto minus a few pixels with CSS?

Tags: css, margin

I want to do this:

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

so that it floats to the center, but I want to move the div 100px to the left so essentially

```
margin: 0 auto 0 [auto minus 100px];
```

so it is 100px to the left of the center.

How do I do this with CSS?

---

NOTE:

This div is overlaid on top of another div. I **cannot** put it inside another larger div.

```
<style>
#one {
 width: 100px;
 margin: ?
}
</style>
<div id="one">
sdgdgffdsg
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE: SOLVED

GGG gave me the solution in the comment.

```
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: You could do `position:relative; left:-100px;`

Comment: It depends on your markup, but `border-right:100px transparent` may work.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 nice, I was thinking of adding some space on the right to "rebalance" it but couldn't think how to do it.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 : nope, that will not work.

Comment: put it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @GGG if you make answer I will choose as best answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Center** using `margin: 0 auto;`
and move **left** using `position: relative; left: -100px;`

```
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
left: -100px;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
position:relative; left:-100px;
```

Comment: chose other one only because it clarifies to add the 0 auto

Comment: Heh, okay, but that was part of you original question, I didn't think it needed to be clarified.

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  You have to wrap in another element which has a fixed margin instead.

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">Hi!</div>
</div>

#foo {
  margin: 0 100px 0 0; /* left margin only is 100px */
}

#bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but in your markup, only margin **right** is given, *not* left. The order is: top right bottom left.

Answer (score -1):

Does your inside div have a fixed width? If so, you could do this:

HTML

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inside {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -150px;
}
```